# java.lang.NullPointerException when appending information to an existing Excel file

Tags: java, excel, exception, excel-2003, jxl

I'm trying to append information to an existing Excel file, but I keep receiving java.lang.NullPointerException. Please refer to the code and exception message below.

**Code**:

```
private WritableSheet appendingSheet;
private static File report;

public void AppendToDoc (String path) throws IOException, WriteException, BiffException {

    this.inputFile = path;
    report = new File(inputFile);

    Workbook appendingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputFile));
    WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"),appendingWorkbook);
    appendingSheet = copy.getSheet("Sheet 1");      
}

public void WriteToDoc (int option, String testName, String execDate, String time, boolean status) throws RowsExceededException, WriteException, IOException, BiffException{        


    int startingRow = NumOfRows(this.inputFile) + 1; //I have a function which finds the number of existing rows in the existing document. It works. 
    Label label = new Label(1, startingRow, "hello", times);    
    appendingSheet.addCell(label);

}
```

**Calling code**:

```
AppendToDoc("C:/Users/smith/ExcelTestFile.xls");
WriteToDoc(2, "This is a test", "executed", timeStamp, true);
```

**Exception message**:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at jxl.write.biff.Styles.getFormat(Styles.java:214)
>       at jxl.write.biff.CellValue.addCellFormat(CellValue.java:468)
>       at jxl.write.biff.CellValue.setCellDetails(CellValue.java:282)
>       at jxl.write.biff.LabelRecord.setCellDetails(LabelRecord.java:216)
>       at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.addCell(WritableSheetImpl.java:1199)
>       at ExcelOperations.WriteToDoc(ExcelOperations.java:149)
>       at ChequeImage.main(ChequeImage.java:174)

**NOTE**: The exception seems to be happening at the line "appendingSheet.addCell(label);".

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT 1**: The below image shows the contents of appendingSheet right before "appendingSheet.addCell(label)" is executed. I'm not exactly sure what it represents, but it certianly doesn't seem to be null. 
[image]

Comment: Well `appendingSheet` instance get initialized in `AppendToDoc` method and limited to that method only. Causing `NPE`  for `WriteToDoc` as `appendingSheet` is `null.`

Comment: It would be helpful to also show the code calling these methods.

Comment: @Smit appendingSheet is a global variable. Even though it's initialized  in AppendToDoc, the value would still be present even after AppendToDoc finishes no?

Comment: @Jonathan Drapeau I will edit my question with calling methods right away.

Comment: `appendingSheet = copy.getSheet("Sheet 1");` Isn't `getSheet` returning null?

Comment: @Hypaa Have you tried debugging it? I am concerned as your `appendingSheet` is not `static`

Comment: @Smit  I just debugged and checked the contents of appendingSheet right before "appendingSheet.addCell(label)" is executed. It is NOT null. I will try to provide a screen shot of when I hover my mouse over appendingSheet.

Comment: @Jean Waghetti as well.

Comment: Apparently you need 10 reputation points to post images... you'll just have be take my word for the fact that appendingSheet isn't null.

Comment: @Hypaa There could be something which is causing `NPE` are you sure you have added correct stacktrace?

Comment: @Smit I've provided more information in Edit 1. Thank you.

Comment: For convenience you have the line is failing in the stack trace, would you please tell us what line is the 149 in the file named 
"ExcelOperations.java"?

Comment: @Hypaa Can you create [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? and as @ Omar said please point us to those lines. Try to give recent full stacktrace and some related code to those exception lines.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I'm familiar with Biff, but POI seems to work in a similar fashion.  It looks as though you have created a workbook:

> WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"),appendingWorkbook);

But then you don't create the sheet that you reference with:

> appendingSheet = copy.getSheet("Sheet 1");

I'm guessing you're getting an NPE because "copy.getSheet("Sheet 1");" is returning null.  Unlike when you simply open a workbook in excel, the API will likely not create that default sheet for you.  I'm betting you'll have to create the sheet object before you're able to add cells.

Comment: Are you sure that is not how null or improperly formatted data is represented in the application?  Maybe try a System.out.println() after "appendingSheet = copy.getSheet("Sheet 1");" to see if the sheet being returned is null or otherwise incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

So...I've managed to solve the problem.

I can't really explain why, but after I redefined "**copy**" and "**appendingWorkbook**" (not appendingSheet) as global variables instead of local to **AppendToDoc()**; as well as added the line **copy.write()**, the program worked...

Thanks everyone for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have face the following Exception while writing the data into an XLS file using JXL API.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jxl.write.biff.Styles.getFormat(Styles.java:214)
    at jxl.write.biff.CellValue.addCellFormat(CellValue.java:468)
    at jxl.write.biff.CellValue.setCellDetails(CellValue.java:282)
    at jxl.write.biff.LabelRecord.setCellDetails(LabelRecord.java:216)
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.addCell(WritableSheetImpl.java:1199)
    at com.java.report.XLS_JXLReport.main(XLS_JXLReport.java:31)
```

I have observed the following error is occurring due to `WritableFont` is empty. Source code from where the exception is raised is:

```
Styles.java:214
    // Do the same with the statically shared fonts
    if (format.getFont() == WritableWorkbook.ARIAL_10_PT) // Line 214
    {
      format.setFont(getArial10Pt());
    }
```

> To avoid this error make sure to provide the **Font Name**.

Sample code using [Java Excel API » 2.6.12](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.12)

```java
public class XLS_JXLReport {
    static String filePath = "C:/Yash/";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JXLException {
        //Creates a writable workbook with the given file name
        jxl.write.WritableWorkbook workbook = jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filePath+"CopyCell.xls"));
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("My Sheet", 0);
        
        // Create cell font and format
        WritableFont cellFont = new jxl.write.WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 16);
            cellFont.setColour(jxl.format.Colour.BLUE);
        WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
            cellFormat.setBackground(jxl.format.Colour.GRAY_25);
        
        //cellFormat = null; // To get the NullPointerException at Styles.java:214. Uncomment this line of code.
        
        // Create the label, specifying content and format
        Label label = new Label(1, 2, "ABCD", cellFormat);
        sheet.addCell(label);
        
        //Create copies of cell in a loop
        WritableCell copiedCell = null;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i ++) {
            copiedCell = label.copyTo(1, 4 + i); //Deep copy cell
            sheet.addCell(copiedCell);
        }
        
        closeWorkbook(workbook);
    }
    public static void closeWorkbook(WritableWorkbook workbook) throws IOException, JXLException {
        if (workbook == null)
            return;
        if (workbook.getNumberOfSheets() == 0) {
            workbook.createSheet("No data", 0); // otherwise pointer error
        }
        //Writes out the data held in this workbook in Excel format
        workbook.write(); 
        //Close and free allocated memory 
        workbook.close(); 
    }
}
```

---

JXL API<sup>[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JXL_(API))</sup> allows users to read, write, create, and modify sheets in an Excel(`.xls`) workbook at runtime. It doesn't support `.xlsx` format.

- JXL API supports Excel documents with versions `Excel 95, 97, 2000, XP, and 2003`. These documents hold the extension `.xls`
- For `.xlsx` use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).